# how to determine if the following sequence is monotonous

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following sequence:
$$U_n =\displaystyle \sum_{k=n}^{2n} \frac1k$$
I need to determine if the sequence is increasing or decreasing; to do this I want to calculate $U_{n+1} - U_n$ and know if it is positive or not. However, I do not know how to simplify such an expression containing sigma.

Comment: $u_{n+1} = u_n + \frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Well, every $\;u_n\;$ is the *ascending* sum of positive elements, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $S_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1k$, then we have

$$\begin{align}
S_{n+1}-S_n&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+2}\frac1k -\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1k\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1n
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Oh I get it now, thank you

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: And please feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit of course.  ;-)